# Replace Special Characters in Field Names in Python

Tags: python, csv, replace, row

I am trying to replace the special characters in the field name (or first row) in my CSV file using python.  There are a lot of questions closely related to special characters but I can't seem to find anything for the first row.  The script I have replaces them in the whole document but I only want it to do it in the first row.  I thought if I used readline instead of readlines, it would work but that just makes most of the file disappear.  Any help would be appreciated.  My code is below.

```
import os, sys, csv

lines = []

with open('C:/Characters.csv', 'r') as input:
    lines = input.readlines()

conversion = '-"/.$'
newtext = '_'
outputLines = []
for line in lines:
    temp = line[:]
    for c in conversion:
        temp = temp.replace(c, newtext)
    outputLines.append(temp)

with open('C:/Characters_out.csv', 'w') as output:
    for line in outputLines:
        output.write(line + "\n")lines = []
```

Comment: I don't know why it is showing "enter code here"  When posting the question, it said to format it but I may have messed it up.

Comment: For code formatting, indent with 4 spaces or by highlighting and pressing the "{}" button in the edit toolbar.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to adjust the first line in the `lines` list, there's no need to iterate over all of them, or even copy into a new list:

```
import csv

lines = []

with open('C:/Characters.csv', 'r') as input:
    lines = input.readlines()

conversion = '-"/.$'
newtext = '_'

for c in conversion:
    lines[0] = lines[0].replace(c, new_text)

with open('C:/Characters_out.csv', 'w') as output:
    for line in lines:
        output.write(line + "\n")
```

You can even do it without the `lines` array at all:

```
import csv

input = open('C:/Characters.csv', 'r')
output = open('C:/Characters_out.csv', 'w')

conversion = '-"/.$'
newtext = '_'

index = 0
for line in input:
    if index == 0:
        for c in conversion:
             line = line.replace(c, new_text)

    output.write(line + "\n")
    index += 1
```

You can also use a regular expression for the conversion:

```
import re
lines[0] = re.sub(r'[-"/\.$]', '_', lines[0])
```

Comment: If the answer solved the problem, you can accept it with the tick mark on the left of the answer. Glad it's working!